# Bootstrap 2 site, tapping on iOS Safari suddenly not working

Tags: ios, twitter-bootstrap, mobile-safari

I have several angry customers on my hand because suddenly a Bootstrap 2.3 site is not responding to any tap input from iOS users. To my knowledge nothing major has changed on the site and I cannot find any errors. The address is https://tevfd.org

I noticed that if I remove `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` tapping works again but I lose my responsive functionality. What is going on??

**UPDATE**

This is also happening on another responsive site, http://coplefire.org, which does not use Bootstrap. What on earth is going on? Did Apple recently change something?? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas? Anything at all? I really need to resolve this quickly. I have searched and searched, cannot find any possible causes. As far as I know it was working as of two days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem tracked down to these lines of code from ShareThis -

```
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
```

See [this page](http://support.sharethis.com/customer/portal/articles/517332-share-widget-faqs#sthash.aV0X7lQf.dpbs) for details. I need a stiff drink.